# Number of equation under bracket

Tags: brackets

How i can get a number to each equation under a bracket

$$\begin{cases} a\leq b \ a>c \ d=2 \ c=0 \end{cases}$$

Thank you

Comment: Use the `empheq` package, instead of `cases` environment.

Comment: i must added \usepackage{empheq}

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{gather}
 a\leq b \\
 a>c \\
 d=2 \\
 c=0 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]